# Casting capturing lambda to function pointer not using std::function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, function-pointers

Consider the following example:

```
using function_pair = std::pair<int, void(*)(void*)>; // This line cannot change
template <class Arg, class F>
function_pair make_function_pair(int i, F&& f)
{
    return function_pair(i, 
    [&](void* x){std::forward<F>(f)(static_cast<Arg*>(x));}); // Not working
}

// Later in code
auto p1 = make_function_pair<char>(1, [](char* x){std::cout<<*x<<std::endl;});
auto p2 = make_function_pair<double>(2, [](double* x){*x = *x*2;});
auto p3 = make_function_pair<float>(3, [](float* x){*x = *x*3;});
```

The code fails to compile because of the capturing lambda (when the lambda does not have to capture `f`, it works). I am wondering how to make this work without using `std::function`, because the computing overhead of `std::function` is huge and I cannot afford that. And even without this practical reason, I am wondering how to solve this "academic" problem without using `std::function`.

Comment: Do you need the second element of function pair to be a function pointer? Only non-capturing lambdas can be converted to one. OTOH, if the function pointer was just a starting point to illustrate what you are trying to do, then you are facing a brickwall with C++11. With C++14, simply use `auto` for the function return type and you avoid the overhead of `std::function`

Comment: I second Pradhan -- as the type of the returned lambda cannot be expressed, your only choice in C++11 is to erase it behind an std::function or similar.

Comment: @Pradhan Yes, I need a function pointer, so that p1, p2 and p3 will all be of the same type.

Comment: Did you measure the overhead of `std::function`?  I doubt it, because you are also capturing by reference, and capturing by reference is a big no-no when you are returning a copy of the lambda from the current scope.  The overhead of a `std::function` is larger than a function pointer, but it isn't ridiculously more if you fall within the small function optimization size.

Comment: After @Yakk's comment, I re-read the code and no longer understand the intent. What is the lambda forwarding in `make_function_pair` trying to achieve? It is wrapping around `f` and capturing nothing else. Why not simply use `f`, which is convertible to a function pointer? For example, `auto p1 = std::make_pair(1, +[](char* x){std::cout<<*x<<std::endl;};`. You can throw in the cast here to `void(void*)` if needed.

Comment: @Pradhan converting from `void(char*)` to `void(void*)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: [In C++20, (stateless) lambda functions are default constructible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722631/why-is-a-lambda-in-c-never-defaultconstructible#comment113972813_38723264), so the problem can be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hack solution is to rely on the fact that a non-capturing lambda doesn't use its state in every C++ implementation I've seen.

```
template<class F>
struct stateless_t {
  constexpr stateless_t() {
    static_assert( std::is_empty<F>::value, "Only works with stateless lambdas" );
  }
  using F_ref = F const&;
  template<class...Ts>
  std::result_of_t<F_ref(Ts...)> operator()(Ts&&...ts)const {
    return (*reinterpret_cast<F const*>(this))(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }
};

template<class F>
stateless_t<F> stateless() { return {}; }

template <class Arg, class F>
function_pair make_function_pair(int i, F const&)
{
  return function_pair(
    i, 
    [](void* x){return stateless<F>()(static_cast<Arg*>(x));}
  );
}
```

This is undefined behavior left right and center, but will probably work with your compiler.

Better alternatives is to use `std::function` and measure the overhead before rejecting the option.  With small function objects, `std::function` has only modest overhead (virtual call instead of function pointer call).

Next, write your own `std::function` with reduced overhead or find one (like fastest possible delegates).  You can, for example, make a faster `std::function` that stores the pointer-to-invoke within the class itself rather then in a vtable.

Or, also UB, but better than above -- convert your stateless lambda to `void(T*)`, then reinterpret_cast that to `void(void*)`.  While still UB, most implementations use binary-compatible pointer sizes, and function pointers that can be cast between.  @Pradhan suggested this above in comments.

In general, avoid UB, as it adds a constant maintenance overhead from that point onward.  You have tested it in your current compiler, but you have to check it works in *every compiler* and *every build* with *every compiler setting used* from now until the end of life of the code for it to be reliable long-term.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have a capturing lambda convertable to a pointer to function. If you think about it, it is rather clear - to capture the variables you need them to be passed into function somehow - and function pointer does not have that option.

Academic solution is to re-implement std::function. No way around this.