# Priority Queue With a Custom Comparator No Matching Constructor

Tags: c++, templates, stl, std, priority-queue

I am trying to create a priority queue with a custom comparator but the following code gives me a compile error:

```
    auto comparator = [](std::pair<std::vector<int>, File&> const &a, std::pair<std::vector<int>, File&> const &b) {
      return a.first.front() > b.first.front();  
};

     std::priority_queue<std::pair<std::vector<uint64_t>, File&>,
      std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<uint64_t>, File&>>,
      decltype(comparator)> pq;
```

This is the error I am getting:

In template: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::priority_queue<std::pair<std::vector, moderndbs::File &>, std::vector<std::pair<std::vector, moderndbs::File &>>, (lambda at

Comment: Your comparator knows how to compare values of type `std::pair<std::vector<int>, File&>`, but you are trying to use it to compare values of a different type `std::pair<std::vector<uint64_t>, File&>`

Comment: This does not fix the problem.

Comment: Since you only pass the type of `comparator` to the priority queue, but not the instance itself, the queue has to default-construct one. However, lambdas are not default-constructible before C++20. You need to compile with C++20 support enabled for this to work, or else pass `comparator` to `pq`'s constructor, as in `std::priority_queue<...> pq{comparator}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a mismatch in your question, between `uint64_t` and `int`. Assuming that this is squared away:

You need at least C++20 in order to compile the shown code. Prior to C++20, lambdas [are not default-constructible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722631/why-is-a-lambda-in-c-never-defaultconstructible), and you attempting to default-construct your `std::priority_queue`.

You need to explicitly pass the comparator to the constructor. Tested with gcc 10, with `-std=c++17`:

```
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

class File{};

void foo()
{
    auto comparator = [](std::pair<std::vector<int>,
                 File &> const &a,
                 std::pair<std::vector<int>,
                 File &> const &b) {
        return a.first.front() > b.first.front();
    };

    std::priority_queue<std::pair<std::vector<int>,
                      File &>,
                std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<int>,
                          File &>
                    >,
                decltype(comparator)> pq{comparator};
}
```

This fails with with a default-constructor `pq`. gcc 10 compiles the default-constructed `pq` with `-std=c++20`.

P.S.: consider replacing the `File &` with `std::reference_wrapper`, unless you really intend to do what the `File &` in `std::pair` will ***really*** do.

Comment: Thank you, Sam! It works now :) File is a custom file class here, can you briefly mention what reference_wrapper does? I will only read these files later, which one should I use in this case :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766939/difference-between-stdreference-wrapper-and-simple-pointer